# Why would java map collector throw a duplicate key on the original object

Tags: java

When running the following code compiled on JDK 8 the exception thrown is

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key 1

which indicates that even though the new key is supposed to be a different object from a different type, the exception still mentions the original object.

```
List<Integer> ints = ImmutableList.of(1, 1);
Map<String, Integer> m = ints.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(intgr -> String.valueOf(intgr + 1), Function.identity()));
```

The mapping function can be arbitrarily complex and totally different objects end up being mapped to the same key, why would this exception behavior be chosen?

I mean why the exception thrown is not "Duplicate key 2"?

Note: in our case the original value that was mapped is a third party class without `toString` implementation so it was impossible to know what caused the duplication.

Comment: Because how to handle case of duplication? I mean next: when key already stored, old value will be erased. So, how stream can understand what this must do with old value?

Comment: With the original object you can handle it in the original input by removing it for example, however with new value you would need to reverse the map process to determine the original object. And with the original value you can always redo the process to get the new value.

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8178142

Comment: @grape_mao your answer sounds reasonable, but as Andy pointed out it's a bug

Comment: @Vic thanks for keeping me informed, that's actually an enhancement :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be a jdk bug. I think it may be resolved in higher version. (I'm using 1.8_162)

You can see `Collectors#throwingMerger`.

```
private static <T> BinaryOperator<T> throwingMerger() {
    return (u,v) -> { throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Duplicate key %s", u)); };
}
```

While the input parameter `u, v` is come from `Map#merge`. It is the old value and new value. So it is `1, 1` in your case. But the error message is `Duplicate key`, it's totally wrong because both `u` and `v` is not key but value.

## EDIT

Checked jdk 10, this bug has been fixed.

See https://github.com/XDean/openjdk/blob/67672eec97164de10a9ca83ddbcef6b42816ed04/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#L174

Now `Collectors.toMap` use its own accumulate function rather than use `Map.merge`.

Comment: It's actually fixed in Java 9. See [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8040892).

Comment: @Jai Thanks, I was just checked java-10 only.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the merge function is called on values, and not on keys.

Excerpt from `HashMap.merge` function (JDK 1.8.0_152):

```
v = remappingFunction.apply(old.value, value);
```

And the merge function in the `Collector.toMap` is:

```
private static <T> BinaryOperator<T> throwingMerger() {
    return (u,v) -> { throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Duplicate key %s", u)); };
}
```

So I'd say it's a kind of inconsistency in the JDK. Instead of returning a message saying about "Duplicate key", the `Collector` should return a message about "Duplicate value".

*EDIT*: Not even an inconsistency but a [JDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8040892) fixed in JDK 9, as pointed out in [Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner)'s and [Jai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970960/jai)'s comment.